# how to find unknown variable in list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
names = ['rick', 'james','robert','michael','jose']

import random


for get in names:

    user_input=input("Enter the name")
    if user_input == get:
        print (get)
```

Is it possible to have this program randomly choose a word from `names` and then ask the user what comes next in the list. then check if it is right and continue on through the loop.

for example the program randomly chooses `robert`. how would i find `names[:4]` and check if it right. I would like to keep the order of the list but choose a str() and then see what comes after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick a random *index* from the list (minus 1).

```
index = random.randrange(len(names) - 1)
```

Now you can print `names[index]` and test if the player guessed right by comparing to `names[index + 1]`:

```
print('I picked: {}'.format(names[index]))
nextname = input('Who is next?')
if nextname == names[index + 1]:
    print('Correct! It is indeed {}'.format(names[index + 1]))
```

If you want to pick names one by one, randomly, then you need to create a shuffled list of indices:

```
indices = list(range(len(names) - 1))
random.shuffle(indices)
for index in indices:
    print('I picked: {}'.format(names[index]))
    nextname = input('Who is next?')
    if nextname == names[index + 1]:
        print('Correct! It is indeed {}'.format(names[index + 1]))
```

This creates a list of integers that can index all but the last name, and uses `random.shuffle()` to give you that list in a random order; no index will be picked twice this way.

Comment: @roippi: no, because for a length 5 list, `index` will be in the range 0 through to *3*. Note the `len(names) - 1`, and you may want to read the `random.randrange()` documentation; the endpoint is not included in the range of numbers picked from (just like `range()` would work).

Comment: my mistake.  It seems wrong to never randomly pick the last element then.

Comment: @roippi: Given the question where the OP wants the player to guess the **next** name, you *have* to restrict the indices to exclude the last name.

Comment: My programs takes it out of the list but it doesn't change itself after i get right. How can change this?

Comment: @user2980929: You mean you want to remove the name after guessing? Which name are you removing?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I don't want to remove it i just want the program not to choose that name again. and i want the program to go through all the names randomly.

Comment: @ruthless: I've updated my answer, still with the assumption you want to loop through all the names *except the last name* (there is no 'next name' to guess there).